# Xamarin.Form обновление данных при переходе на следующую страницу и обратно

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, навигация

Доброе время суток. Есть следующая схема:

Некоторая **ContentPageA** у которой BindingContext = **ViewModel1** хранит некоторый **ObjectA**, затем при клике пользователя, **ViewModel1** с помощью **Navigation.PushAsync()** открывает некоторую **ContentPageB**, у которой BindingContext = **ViewModel2**. Пользователь совершает некоторый выбор, после чего нужно 1) закрыть **ContentPageB**, 2) вернуться к **ContentPageA** и 3) обновить **ObjectA** в соответствии с тем, что пользователь выбрал в **ContentPageB**.

Подскажите, как осуществить правильно пункт 3? Вернуться можно при помощи PopAsync(), но как передать новые данные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наткнулся на занятную штуку MessagingCenter и реализовал через неё: ViewModel1 подписывается на определенное сообщение (Subscribe), ViewModel2 перед переходом назад посылает это самое сообщение (Send), ViewModel1 ловит его и обновляет данные. Не знаю насколько это корректно, но получилось что надо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать посредством передачи ViewModel1 в конструктор ContentPageB. В классе ContentPageB необходимо будет переопределить метод OnBackButtonPressed().
Например:

```
public partial class ContentPageB : ContentPage
{
    private ViewModel _viewModel;

    public ContentPageB (ViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        _viewModel = vm
        this.BindingContext = ViewModel2;
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        _viewModel.ObjectA = ViewModel2.ObjectB;
        base.OnBackButtonPressed();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, интересный вариант, по перед тем как прочёл его, наткнулся на занятную штуку MessagingCenter и реализовал через неё: ViewModel1 подписывается на определенное сообщение (Subscribe), ViewModel2 перед переходом назад посылает это самое сообщение (Send), ViewModel1 ловит его и обновляет данные. Не знаю насколько это корректно, но получилось что надо.

Comment: @Лев добавьте свой вариант как ответ и отметьте его как правильный, чтобы вопрос не висел открытым.